# Trying to batch insert .csv using JPA/hibernate not working as intended

Tags: java, csv, jpa

I'm trying to upload a .csv using servlets and insert the data into DB for my school project. I got it working creating a new EntityManager for every commit and it was taking hours for the upload. I researched for batch inserts and this is what I have come up with:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
int i = 0;
int batchsize = 500;

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
i++
String row = scanner.next();
String[] column = row.split(";");
Entity e = new Entity();
e.setSomeValue(column[1]);
entityManager.persist(e);
if(i%batchsize == 0) {
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();
}}
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I think it worked fine the first time, it inserted 90k rows into DB, but trying to upload second file it seemed to work but at the end no new rows were added.
I have set entityManager.setFlushMode (FlushModeType.COMMIT) & entity's PK is auto generated Sequence, not generated by DB.
Would it have anything to do with:

> On commit, transaction was marked for roll-back only, rolling back?

edit: forgot i++

Comment: `entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();` is called every iteration as `0%500 == 0` is always the case

Comment: i forgot to put it, but first thing in the while loop I call 'i++'